# PHP - Load a div with filtering option when two date fields are filled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have developed a leave request page with PHP,Javascript and CSS. I need when user choose the same date on two date fields then will show the div for a option with two radio buttons for halfday leave or fullday leave, please suggest me if any possibilities for this..

Comment: show us what you have already done please

Answer (score 2):

We can use jQuery's `.val()` method to check the date value. If two of them equal, then use `.show()` to display the extra elements, else use `.hide()` to not show them.

```
Start: <input type="date" name="s" id="s" onchange="check()"><br>
End: <input type="date" name="e" id="e" onchange="check()">
<div id="detail" style="display:none">
    <select>
        <option>Full day</option>
        <option>Half day</option>
    </select>
</div>

function check() {
    if ($('#s').val() == $('#e').val()) {
        $('#detail').show();
    } else {
        $('#detail').hide();
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KDQS/)

Comment: <input type="date"> is not working

Comment: @Ashoksri, just replace them with your date fields

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title>MAFIREE :: LEAVE</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function check() {
    if ($('#s').val() == $('#e').val()) {
        $('#detail').show();
    } else {
        $('#detail').hide();
    }
}
</script>
<body>
Start: <input type="date" name="s" id="s" onchange="check()"><br>
End: <input type="date" name="e" id="e" onchange="check()">
<div id="detail" style="display:none">
    <select>
        <option>Full day</option>
        <option>Half day</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>